How should I reinforce my deck's framing to support stair stringers?
The outside joist (2x10) that the stringers would attach to appears to be screwed to the ledger board with only a few screws, and without any hanger. I'm worried about attaching five stringers (I'll need 14-16 steps depending on how i decide to run the stairs) to get to the ground with so little support.
How do I reinforce the outside joist to support stair stringers?

Do I need a post under the joist adjacent to the house? It seems like that would take away from the aesthetics of it.
Or, can I somehow beef up joist support to the ledger? If so, how?
Or, would the concept as seen in the design also work? Adding two 4x4 posts mid-span.


Here you can see the 2x10 and three screws screwed into the ledger board. You can also see a 2x6 that I added underneath for stringer attachment. It appears to be a little bent, maybe from the sun. That's not a problem, i can always replace it with another 2x6.


I've removed the fascia so that i may get a closer look at the joist-ledger connection. That's why it doesn't look even.

This is underneath the deck. You can see blocking that the metal guardrail is attached to from above. It actually split. But I will need a new guardrail post for the stairs anyways and that's when I'll add new blocking.
In this picture, you do not see 2x6 because it was taken prior.

You can see how I went about to attach 2x6 underneath the 2x10 joist. Since I am slowly moving through this project, I did not screw all of the screws yet, just left it hanging there for now. If need be, i can always add a 2x4 that spans across the 2x10 and 2x6 and use lag screws for an even stronger connection.

Here is an idea I've been working with of how I'd like the stairs to look. Preferably I'd use one post in the middle at two separate locations and add knee braces from the edges of the beam to the post (not seen in design picture).
So the ultimate question is, how do I create a strong set up at the outside joist (which lacks any hanger) so that I can securely attach stair stringers?

There should 2 joists at that outside edge to help support the stringers. What is the piece that is lower than the joists? Is it for attaching the stringers to? If so it is in the way. Typically I cut my carriages so an extra riser goes behind the doubled outside joists and set snugly between that and the next joist back. If the explanation is not clear enough I can make a scale drawing if need be. Also, that long of a run of stairs needs a center support along it's run. That will be very springy.

I think I'd do a few things here. The goal is to create rigidity in the rim so that you don't have bounce when the stairs are used.

Add an angle bracket or modified standard joist hanger to connect the end joist to the ledger. In some cases I've simply bent the one flange of a standard hanger flat, on plane with the suspension portion, and nailed it to the end of the ledger. End grain isn't ideal, but with all the other nails it'll be fairly solid. Or just put an angle plate on the inside part of the joint. Access is obviously a challenge, but maybe you swing the second joist out of position temporarily.

Block between the first and second joists on say 24" centers. Use full-height lumber and screw from both sides with about four 3" or longer screws. This will create a box structure that's more rigid on both vertical and horizontal axes. Two-by lumber ripped to width and installed vertically might be more robust than horizontal shorty 2x10s, which may tend to split on the grain.


Regarding your stairway plan, don't add posts. They're cumbersome, ugly, and costly. Just use enough stringers of appropriate size. I don't have all the dimensions, but four 2x12 stringers should be plenty rigid, and if it's not quite where you want it you can add 2x4s to the sides of the inner ones for more stiffness.
